# kubectl port-forward does not return when connection lost

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, command-line-interface, kubectl

The `help` of the `kubectl port-forward` says `The forwarding session ends when the selected pod terminates, and rerun of the command is needed to resume forwarding.`

Although it does not auto-reconnect when the pod terminates the command does not return either and just hangs with errors:

```
E0929 11:57:50.187945   62466 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 8000 -> 8080: error forwarding port 8080 to pod a1fe1d167955e1c345e0f8026c4efa70a84b9d46029037ebc5b69d9da5d30249, uid : network namespace for sandbox "a1fe1d167955e1c345e0f8026c4efa70a84b9d46029037ebc5b69d9da5d30249" is closed
Handling connection for 8000
E0929 12:02:44.505938   62466 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 8000 -> 8080: error forwarding port 8080 to pod a1fe1d167955e1c345e0f8026c4efa70a84b9d46029037ebc5b69d9da5d30249, uid : failed to find sandbox "a1fe1d167955e1c345e0f8026c4efa70a84b9d46029037ebc5b69d9da5d30249" in store: not found
```

I would like it to return so that I can handle this error and make the script that will rerun it.

Is there any way or workaround for how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information, described on [Kubernetes Issues page on GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67059), I can suppose that it is a normal behavior for your case: port-forward connection cannot be canceled on pod deletion, since there is no a connection management inside REST connectors on server side.

> A connection being maintained from kubectl all the way through to the kubelet hanging open even if the pod doesn't exist.

> We'll proxy a websocket connection kubectl->kubeapiserver->kubelet on port-forward.

Comment: Hello @WytrzymałyWiktor! It does explain why it does not return but does not solve the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Recursive function?

```
kpf(){ kubectl port-forward $type/$object $LOCAL:$REMOTE $ns || kpf; }
```

Also check [this](https://github.com/vaniacer/kube-dialog)

Comment: The problem is that the `kubectl port-forward` does not return, so it won't work